# ggplot geom_text not seating on top of bars

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, geom-text

I have some data where some groups do not appear on all months. I am plotting this on a bar graph but with a text label showing the numerical values but the text are not seating on top of each bar.  I tried using the position "dodge" for the labels but with no success.

Below is a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)

data.frame(Month = as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01","2015-01-01",
"2015-02-01","2015-02-01","2015-02-01")),
       types = rep(LETTERS[1:3],2),
       percent = c(0.2,NA,NA,.39,.89,.59)) %>%
  ggplot( aes(x = Month, y = percent, fill = types)) +  
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent) +
  scale_x_date(labels = date_format("%Y-%b")) +
  geom_text(stat = 'identity', 
        aes(label = ifelse(percent > .02,
                           paste(round(percent*100,0),"%",sep = "") ,'')))
```

This is what it looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple suggestions,

1. Use `lubridate` for working with dates
2. Set `Months` to a factor variable.  This will help when using `position_dodge()`.

Try using the code below.  If you have more than one year of data you may consider constructing the month factor variable with the year appended to the month.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)

data.frame(Month = months(ymd(c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01","2015-01-01", "2015-02-01","2015-02-01","2015-02-01"))),
           types = rep(LETTERS[1:3],2),
           percent = c(0.2,NA,NA,.39,.89,.59)) %>%
  mutate(Month = factor(Month, levels = month.name),
         label = ifelse(!is.na(percent), paste0(round(percent*100), "%"), "")) %>% 
  ggplot() + 
  aes(x = Month, y = percent, fill = types) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(w = 0.75)) + 
  geom_text(position = position_dodge(w = 0.75), 
            aes(ymax = percent, label = label))
```

[image]